# Scheme (DrRacket) - Calling Generalized / Abstracted Function with Another Function

Tags: function, scheme, racket, abstraction

For reference I am programming with Scheme using DrRacket.

For this problem I am making a generalized / abstracted function **(which aren't using higher-order functions and/or lambda)** called `tally-by` of the function `tally-by-place-points` which is defined below:

```
(define listofCandidates
  (list "Blake" "Ash" "Bob" "Will" "Joey"))

;; Signature: tally-by-place-points: 
;;              list-of-candidates list-of-votes -> list-of-Voting-Tallies
;; Purpose: Consumes a list of candidate names and a list of votes and 
;;          produces a list of voting-tallies.
;;          (Points-Per-Place strategy).
;; Tests:
(check-expect (tally-by-place-points empty empty) empty)
(check-expect (tally-by-place-points listofCandidates listofVotes) 
              (cons (make-voting-tally "Blake" 7)
               (cons (make-voting-tally "Ash" 3)
                (cons (make-voting-tally "Bob" 5)
                 (cons (make-voting-tally "Will" 1)
                  (cons (make-voting-tally "Joey" 2) empty))))))
;; Define:
(define (tally-by-place-points aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (total-points-for (first aloc) alov))
                (tally-by-place-points (rest aloc) alov))]))
```

This is what I came up with **(not sure if it is correct)**:

```
;; Signature: tally-by: (helper function)
;;              list-of-candidates list-of-votes -> list-of-Voting-Tallies
;; Purpose: Consumes a helper function, a list of candidate names, 
;;          and a list of votes and produces a list of voting-tallies.
;; Define:
(define (tally-by helper aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (tally-by helper (first aloc) alov))
                (tally-by helper (rest aloc) alov))]))
```

I should note that this is the helper function I am referring to, `total-points-for`:

```
;; Signature: total-points-for: string list-of-strings -> number
;; Purpose: Consumes a name and a list of votes and produces the
;;          number of points that the given name has received
;;          using a points-per-place strategy.
;; Tests:
(check-expect (total-points-for "Ash" empty) 0)
(check-expect (total-points-for "Ash" listofVotes) 3)
(check-expect (total-points-for "Blake" listofVotes) 7)
(check-expect (total-points-for "Bob" listofVotes) 5)
(check-expect (total-points-for "Will" listofVotes) 1)
(check-expect (total-points-for "Joey" listofVotes) 2)
(check-expect (total-points-for "Brad" listofVotes) 0)
;; Define:
(define (total-points-for cand alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? alov) 0]
    [(string=? (vote-choice1 (first alov)) cand) 
                        (+ 3 (total-points-for cand (rest alov)))]
    [(string=? (vote-choice2 (first alov)) cand) 
                        (+ 2 (total-points-for cand (rest alov)))]
    [(string=? (vote-choice3 (first alov)) cand) 
                        (+ 1 (total-points-for cand (rest alov)))]
    [else (total-points-for cand (rest alov))]))
```

I now have to modify the `tally-by-place-points` function to call the generalized / abstracted function `tally-by` I just made. I should note that the signature, purpose, and check-expects are all correct. This is the function I came up with, **although the definition is not correct**:

```
;; Signature: tally-by-place-points: 
;;              list-of-candidates list-of-votes -> list-of-Voting-Tallies
;; Purpose: Consumes a list of candidate names and a list of votes 
;;          and produces a list of voting-tallies.
;;          (Points-Per-Place strategy).
;; Tests:
(check-expect (tally-by-place-points empty empty) empty)
(check-expect (tally-by-place-points listofCandidates listofVotes) 
              (cons (make-voting-tally "Blake" 7)
               (cons (make-voting-tally "Ash" 3)
                (cons (make-voting-tally "Bob" 5)
                 (cons (make-voting-tally "Will" 1)
                  (cons (make-voting-tally "Joey" 2) empty))))))
;; Define:
(define (tally-by-place-points aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (tally-by (first aloc) alov))
                (tally-by (rest aloc) alov))]))
```

I am hoping someone is able to assist me with my `tally-by` and modified `tally-by-place-points` function definitions as I am unsure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tally-by-place-points you call `(total-points-for (first aloc) alov)` to get the place points. In `tally-by` you are supposed to be able to do exactly the same if you pass `total-points-for` as argument `helper`. Thus you need to replace references to `total-points-for` with `helper` and also pass helper when recursing:

```
(define (tally-by helper aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (helper (first aloc) alov))
                (tally-by helper (rest aloc) alov))]))
```

In `tally-by-place-points` which using `tally-by` would just call `tally` by with the argument it got with the correct `helper`:

```
(define  (tally-by-place-points aloc alov)
  (tally-by total-points-for aloc alov))
```

BTW your mention of which language you are using is ambiguous. From the syntax you are most likely programming racket in DrRacket. I guess you first line is either `#lang scheme` (`#!scheme` for short) or `#!racket`, which are synonyms and not a official Scheme language. For an actual Scheme language you need to use `#!r6rs` or `#!r5rs` and program according to those.

Answer (score 2):

*Abstraction* is a purely syntactical transformation !  It's just *beta-reduction* in reverse:

```
..... a .....     ==>     (λa.  ..... a ..... ) a
```

That is, you just make some entity that you use into a function's parameter, and pass that entity as an argument in the function's call. That way, what was specific before is now generalized, turned into a parameter, abstracted over:

```
(define (tally-by-place-points      aloc alov)
  (cond         ; ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (total-points-for (first aloc) alov))
                           ;       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                (tally-by-place-points (rest aloc) alov))]))
```

is re-written as

```
(define (tally-by   place-points    aloc alov)
  (cond         ;   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (place-points     (first aloc) alov))
                           ;       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                (tally-by-place-points (rest aloc) alov))]))
```

so that the call

```
(tally-by   total-points-for   aloc alov)
```

is equivalent to the previous call

```
(tally-by-place-points         aloc alov)
```

This of course needs to be tidied up in the recursion call - it too needs to be transformed:

```
(define (tally-by   place-points    aloc alov)
  (cond         ;   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (place-points     (first aloc) alov))
                (tally-by   place-points   (rest aloc) alov))]))
                        ;   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

because we replace `(tally-by-place-points ...` with `(tally-by  place-points ...` — everywhere.

Of course we can rename that `place-points` parameter now, with any name we want (as long as the name is unique).